# Ruby capture words between two colons

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to capture any word between two colons. I tried with this ([try on Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/5ITx3l9iXT)):

```
(\:.*\:)
```

> Hello :name:
>
> What are you doing today, :title:?
>
> $:name:, have a lovely :event:.

It works except the last line it captures this:

> Match 3
>   1. :name:, have a lovely :event:

It's getting tripped up by the second (closing) colon and the third (opening) colon. It should capture `:name:` and `:event:` individually on that last line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a non-greedy regular expression:

```
(\:.*?\:)
```

The `.*?` will match the shortest possible string, whereas `.*` matches the longest string found.

Answer (score 6):

For any *word between* two colons:

```
(?<=:)\b.*?\b(?=:)
```

[Rubular link](http://rubular.com/r/RkBYtUvfgQ)

Comment: **This is the correct answer**. It excludes the surrounding colons _and_ omits unwanted in-between information (like ', have a lovely' in the example).

Answer (score 2):

```
(\:[^:]*\:)
```

`[^:]` means "anything but a ':'.

Please be aware that this expression will match "::" also.

Here is your rubular link updated: http://rubular.com/r/VtwhIqtbli.

Comment: Please be aware that this exp will match "::" also.